# Why eks cluster doesn't have corresponding logs in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

Control plane logging for EKS + CloudWatch is relatively new. I see this in my EKS account:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

but when I click the link at the bottom to go to CloudWatch there are no logs for this cluster, it's not listed here:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to disable it in the Amazon console for now, and enable again with the AWS CLI, and then monitor the status of your log configuration update with the procedure described in official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html%20as%20described%20in%20official%20documentation). 
This should give you in theory some meaningful information about the status of EKS logging integration with CloudWatch.